# PHP - Calling Relative URL within = 'xx' apostrophe's

Tags: php, include, apostrophe, relative-url

I'm trying to insert a relative URL in the code below before "/images" in $thumb_directory and $orig_directory however I'm not sure how to do so within 'apostrophe's'.  Also, this is a WordPress website, so if anyone knows how to call the function  within '/images', like so: '/images' please let me know (I realize that what I just typed is incorrect syntax).

```
<?php
/* Configuration Start */
$thumb_directory = '/images';
$orig_directory = '/images';
$stage_width=600;
$stage_height=400;
/* Configuration end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the relative path is in the variable `$rel_path`,
use double quotes:

```
$thumb_directory = "$rel_path/images";
$orig_directory = "$rel_path/images";
```

With double quotes variables (starting with `$`) are replaced by their value, but this doesn't happen with single quotes.

Or use string concatenation:

```
$thumb_directory = $rel_path . '/images';
$orig_directory = $rel_path . '/images';
```

**EDIT**

If your relative path comes from `bloginfo('template_directory')`, simply add the following line *before* using `$rel_path` (so before the lines above):

```
$rel_path = bloginfo('template_directory');
```

This sets the variable with the path you want.
Ensure all these lines are within the PHP processing tags `<?php` and `?>`, and don't forget the semicolon `;` at the end of the assignment line ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm developing this as part of a WordPress theme and I'd like to use the WordPress function

    <?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>

Do you know how I could substitute $rel_path with  bloginfo('template_directory')?